# Server worlds are not loading in/floating in mid-air

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an iPad mini. I play lots of Lifeboat survival Games on it but now I have issues.

When I join *any* server, I am floating on air and all I can see is the sun and clouds. When I go on third person, I can zoom around myself. Behind me is the sun and in front of me is... another sun?

[image: screenshot of floating in void]

Sometimes I would see people but they don't move. And sometimes it works normally. I tried waiting for a few minutes, but that didn't change anything.

It was working for a few months actually but since I got a new wifi booster, it all stopped I don't know why, but I think it might be the wifi boosters problem.

I don't want to delete Minecraft PE again because I have a mansion and Pokemon statues so please tell me what to do. I told Mojang on the App Store but nobody helped. When it does not load, I force close the app and open again but no changes.

Comment: It also works for me after waiting about 10-20 seconds. Have you tried giving it some time to load?

Comment: I waited for a minute or two right now. It's not working still. I don't know what to do still  I just wanna play mc 

Comment: Just for the info, what you have happens when your device knows there's a server there, just can't load any data (blocks, players, etc.) from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of possible things that will occur, also in PC:

1. Check your Internet connection. Maybe giving your internet a google search or a speed test.
2. Test for another server. The server may be having too much traffic, so that it can't send you any data, causing a blank world to show up. (Lifeboat is a popular server)
   EDIT: Maybe you can test on low-players servers.
3. Check if the server's versions is it same as yours.
4. Try reinstalling MCPE. You can also make a world backup in iOS: [www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxUgOoO1xOE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxUgOoO1xOE).
5. Try downgrading/updating your MCPE. I don't really know how to in ios, but you can google search it. Maybe jailbreaking it?
6. Try the server at another device. You can get another one like Android and test if it works on that phone.
7. Maybe leave it over than 10 min, if it still  doesn't work, 30 min.
8. Test the server at another WiFi hotspot. Maybe going to Starbucks and test if it works or going to your friend's house?

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting to any other server, the issue might be the server's issue.

Comment: No, it's on all servers 

Comment: Try uninstalling/reinstalling minecraft, if that doesn't work, then it's mostly your network that has an issue.

Comment: As I said, I do not want to do that and I done it before and lost my worlds.

Comment: then I can't help you...